# Mail Extension in yii-framework?

Tags: email, yii, sendmail, yii-extensions

Which is the best Mail extension to send mail in yii framework?

In yii site I got this type of extension

1. wkd-swiftmailer
2. yii-dkim
3. swiftmailer
4. mail
5. phpmailer
6. email
7. mailer

Comment: I don't think this question has an answer. There's no such thing as "best" in general, only fitness relative to a given set of requirements.

Comment: PHP mailers do only a few actions. Why don't you take one of them (the most well-known one, e.g. PhpMailer) and test, then decide did you lik it or not? :)

Comment: Did you found the best one?? if you ve to recommend what would it be?

Answer (score 0):

i think i cant vote for this, because i have tried only one and it is phpmailer. No problem with it and can send both plain and html. Never used with attachment and for now not planing to search for new mail extensions :)